# a python script that reads keystroke and mouse movements from a file and repeats them

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I was trying to follow and recreate this tutorial / situation :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZbcN-omvkg

I see that he has using a script written in python that has recorded the keystroke and the mouse movements. Since I want to make the forest as close as possibile as it is originally,I've thought to write on a text file every keystroke and mouse movement that appears on the screen and then with some kind of script I would like that blender read the informations from the file and then it recreates the whole animation. Is this possibile ? Do you know of some script that does it ? Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: i think there is macro's addon (record actions then repeats them )

Comment: can you provide the link where I can get it ?

Comment: see [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343029-Macro-script-runner-make-your-operator-prototyping-faster)  and [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Development/Macros_Recorder)  ,also in the video he is not using a script to do  that it's just a  normal work in timelapse